# Android keep button or view in front of all activities within the app without using baseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

After a lot of time spent I can't find the solution. I want a button or any clickable view should stay visible for all activities and it should be only for one specific app not like chat heads. I am basically making a library so that's why I can't use base activity.I have attached the image as well for a better explanation. How can I achieve this any suggestions? thankyou...

I[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a ViewOverlay. This is the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay).

ViewOverlay is usually tied to a single view, but if you wrap it in a fragment, you should be able to attach it to each view in your application. This should create the effect of an of an application scoped overlay.

There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but I am not aware of it.

EDIT: You can also wrap your layouts inside a frame layout(s) along with a seperate nested view (the view that you want to keep on top of the stack).

Frame layout creates a 'stack' of inner views. If you use this approach, you can programmatically ensure that there are exactly two views present and visible as children of your frame layout at all times. one will be the layout tied to your current activity. The other will be the view that you want to be overlayed.

I know that the term 'programmatically ensure' is vague. This is because there are many ways to make this happen. It is up to you to decide which way best suits your needs.